# bootstrap no respeta los estilos de la tabla en el media print

Tags: bootstrap

Buena tarde tengo el inconveniente de que bootstrap no me respeta los estilos de esta pequeña tabla al momento de imprimir ya aplique algunas soluciones como la de entrar directo al archivo bootstrap , o de colocar puros !important en la hoja de estilo el detalle , con el archivo bootstrap es que no puedo alterar el archivo ya que se trabaja en conjunto y hay otros compañeros que si usan el !important entonces no lo puedo descartar , haber si de casualidad ustedes sabe alguna solución diferente.

Les dejo el codigo y ahi vienen los colores que deberia imprimir lo cual no los muestras , como nota tambien ya revise graficos de fondo de google.

GRACIAS!

```
<div style="background-color:#fc808a;  repeat-x ; height: 15px ;width:85% ;"></div>
<div id="cont_K-medias_mapaTematicodivfastview" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <table id="tblEstra_mapaTematicodivfastview1" class="table">
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;">Frecuencia</td>
            <td></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left;font-weight: bold;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center;width:20%;">1*</td>
            <td style="width:10%;">
                <div style="background-color:#fc808a; repeat-x; height: 15px;width:85%;"></div>
            </td>
            <td style="width:70%;">más de 8,811,266 a 17,363,387</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center;width:20%;">3</td>
            <td style="width:10%;">
                <div style="background-color:#E08759; repeat-x; height: 15px;width:85%;"></div>
            </td>
            <td style="width:70%;">más de 6,313,789 a 8,811,266</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center;width:20%;">5</td>
            <td style="width:10%;">
                <div style="background-color:#C591CF; repeat-x; height: 15px;width:85%;"></div>
            </td>
            <td style="width:70%;">más de 4,061,497 a 6,313,789</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center;width:20%;">11</td>
            <td style="width:10%;">
                <div style="background-color:#FCCB75; repeat-x; height: 15px;width:85%;"></div>
            </td>
            <td style="width:70%;">más de 2,172,839 a 4,061,497</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center;width:20%;">12</td>
            <td style="width:10%;">
                <div style="background-color:#7EFEBA; repeat-x; height: 15px;width:85%;"></div>
            </td>
            <td style="width:70%;">de 747,801 a 2,172,839</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: left;" colspan="3">*Unidades geográficas con valores que se alejan del resto. <a
                    href="/componentes/mapaTematico/doc/nota_cug.pdf" target="_blank">Ver más</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya probaste incluyendo los estilos en un css con el atributo media?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
```

Los estilos irían dentro del media print:

```
@media print {
   * { color: black; background: white; }
   table { font-size: 80%; }
}
```

Comment: si tambien mi estimado y nada sigue sin aparecer los estilos por culpa de bootstrap